# If else de data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tenho uma viewbag, e queria exibir datas de no maximo 1 dia antes do dia atual, fiz o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso, qual alternativa eu teria?

```
if (item.DataHora < DateTime.Now - 1)
{
//codigo
}
```

Comment: Que tal `item.DataHora > DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [.AddDays()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx). Com ele você pode passar um valor positivo para adicionar dias, ou um valor negativo para subtrair.

```
if (item.DataHora > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
{
//codigo
}
```

Veja um [exemplo no .netFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjGlOR)

Lembrando que também existem variações para dias, meses, anos, segundos, etc...

Comment: valeu @Randrade, deu certinho